# Change the position of image in tableView in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to show image in each tableView's cell at middle of it for that in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method i can customize each cell like to my need

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                            [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                             pathForResource:@"phone" 
                             ofType:@"png"]];

infoView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
lblCell1 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (cell.frame.size.width)/3, cell.frame.size.height)]autorelease];
lblCell1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[infoView addSubview:lblCell1];
imgCell1 = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.width)/3, cell.frame.size.width, 30, (cell.frame.size.height)/2)]autorelease];
[infoView addSubview:imgCell1];
lblCell2 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((cell.frame.size.width)/3)+30, 0, cell.frame.size.width,(cell.frame.size.height)/2 )]autorelease];
lblCell2.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[infoView addSubview:lblCell2];
lblCell3 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.width)/3, (cell.frame.size.height)/2, cell.frame.size.width, (cell.frame.size.height)/2)]autorelease];
lblCell3.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
[infoView addSubview:lblCell3];

[cell.contentView addSubview:infoView];
//[cell.contentView addSubview:imgCell1];
//[cell.contentView addSubview:lblCell2];
//[cell.contentView addSubview:lblCell3];

Player *doc = [[Player alloc]init];
NSMutableArray* reversedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: _data] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];

doc = [reversedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
lblCell1.text = doc.name;
lblCell2.text = doc.email;
lblCell3.text = doc.phone;
imgCell1.image = backgroundImage;
[imgCell1 sizeToFit];
//  cell.imgCell1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"phone.png"];
return cell;
```

but the image is not set in the UIImageView frame.
where i'm wrong & what i do for show image at the middle of tableview each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cell.image` won't help you here.

Pin the image to a `UIImageView` and then add the `UIImageView` object to the `contentView` of the cell just like you do for the other cases. And set the frame for the `UIImageView` as usual. You should see your desired result.

Edit as following

To be clearer in case I was vague. You have say:

```
UIImage *image = blah blah blah;
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.image = image;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(blah,blah,blah,blah); // position it to the middle 

[[cell contentView] addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: it's work same as my code means that image appear at where my row is not shown means if in tableview no. of rows is suppose 5 then image shows at row started with index no. 10 & goes upto 14 but not shows at right place. what can I do to set image at proper place.

Comment: Are you setting the imageview's frame properly using CGRectMake?

Comment: You also need to implement the height method for the cells. Google on how to set the height custom.

Comment: I was check imageview frame property i declare it but not works then i used its backgroundcolor property for check the co-ordination of imagevew it goes wrong finally i set its with help of bgcolor & set the issue